# Failed building wheel for ssh-python

Tags: python, ssh, pip, openssl

When I try to install parallel ssh I get this error in red for some reason.I think the problem is with open ssl and with building wheel for ssh2-python

```
Building wheels for collected packages: ssh2-python, ssh-python
  Building wheel for ssh2-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-v1bw54kg'
       cwd: C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27034.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  CMake Error at C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
    Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
    system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:486 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    src/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-88x5vkqr/ssh2-python/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\setup.py", line 36, in <module>
      build_ssh2()
    File "C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\_setup_libssh2.py", line 21, in build_ssh2
      check_call('cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    File "c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh2-python
```

Then Here it tries using other file I dont really know

```
  Running setup.py clean for ssh2-python
  Building wheel for ssh-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1w9bt85h'
       cwd: C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh-python\
  Complete output (79 lines):
  Windows platform: True, Python major version: 3.\running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  running egg_info
  writing ssh_python.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to ssh_python.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to ssh_python.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'ssh_python.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docker'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
  writing manifest file 'ssh_python.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying ssh\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\c_callbacks.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\c_legacy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\c_sftp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\c_ssh.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\c_ssh2.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\callbacks.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\callbacks.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\callbacks.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\channel.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\channel.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\channel.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\connector.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\connector.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\connector.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\error_codes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\error_codes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\event.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\event.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\event.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\exceptions.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\exceptions.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\key.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\key.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\key.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\keytypes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\keytypes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\keytypes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\options.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\options.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\options.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\scp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\scp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\scp.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\session.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\session.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\session.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_attributes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_attributes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_attributes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_handles.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_handles.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_handles.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_statvfs.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_statvfs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\sftp_statvfs.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\utils.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  copying ssh\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh
  running build_ext
  building 'ssh.callbacks' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ssh
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilibssh/include "-Ic:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include" "-Ic:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcssh\callbacks.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ssh\callbacks.obj
  callbacks.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:/usr/local/lib "/LIBPATH:c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs" "/LIBPATH:c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x86" ssh.lib Ws2_32.lib user32.lib libcrypto32MD.lib libssl32MD.lib zlibstatic.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_callbacks build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ssh\callbacks.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\ssh\callbacks.cp38-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ssh\callbacks.cp38-win32.lib
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'ssh.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh-python
  Running setup.py clean for ssh-python
Failed to build ssh2-python ssh-python
Installing collected packages: ssh2-python, ssh-python, parallel-ssh
    Running setup.py install for ssh2-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2htv8zya\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\ssh2-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\
    Complete output (22 lines):
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
    CMake Error at C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
      Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
      system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
      OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:486 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      src/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/MR Ihab Badr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-88x5vkqr/ssh2-python/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\setup.py", line 36, in <module>
        build_ssh2()
      File "C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88x5vkqr\ssh2-python\_setup_libssh2.py", line 21, in build_ssh2
        check_call('cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
      File "c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MR Ihab Badr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-88x5vkqr\\ssh2-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MR Ihab Badr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2htv8zya\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mr ihab badr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\ssh2-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

can anyone help ? I'm not that experienced with python also I tried installing ssh2-python and I got a similar error

Answer (score 0):

Wheels - Python binary packages - are provided for most platforms for those packages, including Windows for Python 3.5-3.9 (64 bit).

The above is trying to install on 32-bit Python on Windows, for which binary packages are not provided.

It therefore tries to build from source, which is failing for lack of dependencies:

`missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY`

Can either:

- Try and get them to build on 32-bit Windows (not recommended)
- Use Python 64-bit

The latter will enable use of binary packages and does not require compiling. The former is a PITA.